# Как подставить в функцию спецсимволы из строки?

Tags: php

На входе у нас обычная строка, куда пользователь вводит символ разделения по строкам из файла(т.е в файле уже присутствует этот символ, чтобы разделить строку). Но сама проблема, что функция не распознает именно служебные символы(Например, переноса строки).

```
<form method = "post">
    Введите имя файла: <input type = "text" name = "str">
    Введите разделитель: <input type = "text" name = "spl">  //сюда вводим какой-нибудь символ разделитель
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

```
<?php
    $directory = './uploads/';
    if(isset($_POST['str'])){
        $s = $_POST['str'];
        if(file_exists($directory.$s)){
            $f = fopen("$directory$s","r"); //открываем файл
            $text = fread($f,filesize("$directory$s")); //читаем текст
            $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'utf-8', 'cp1251'); //правим кодировку
            $Split = $_POST['spl']; //извлекаем символ из формовой строки для того, чтобы разделить текст на строки
            $sp = explode("$Split",$text); //вот тут основная проблема, распознает все, кроме спецсимволов
            echo $sp[0]; //для примера
        }else
            echo 'такого файла на сервере нет!';
    }else echo 'пусто';

?>
```

Comment: А где собственно увидеть что у Вас не так?  Приведите пример что-ли.

Comment: Ну я комментарием пометил) Вот как засунуть в функцию explode или preg_split в первый параметр именно спецсимволы. Из текстовой строки в форме html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проблема решается if или switch, спецсимволов не так много, поэтому такой метод подойдет. Но я думаю, что есть варианты короче, чтобы сократить код.